# How to format UILabel text to locale specific NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsnumberformatter

I have a `UILabel` to show input text (which has decimal numbers). What I am trying to do is, that the `UILabel` text can be shown as per locale. E.g.-

> "1234.56" should be shown as "1,234.56" for US locale, "1.234,56" for DE (Germany) locale and so on.

Below is what I have done to achieve this -

```
NSNumberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
NSNumberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: language)
NSNumberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 16

let displayVal: Double = NSNumberFormatter.numberFromString(displayText.text!).doubleValue
displayText.text = NSNumberFormatter.stringFromNumber(displayVal)
```

Where `displayText` is the `UILabel` to display input.

It works fine until 4 digits i.e. "1234" was shown as "1,234" (for US locale). But as soon as 5th digit gets added, `nil` returned for `displayVal` constant variable.

I could guess from the function definition that there is failure in formatting `displayText` text string which may be "1,2345" when `numberFromString` tried to format it as per US locale but failed as this does not comply to US locale format.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this or nicer way of implementation?

Comment: What is the value for `language` and `displayText.text` that gives you nil?

Comment: @dan , the values are `language=en-US` and `displayText.text="1,2345"`

Comment: What does your question have to do with recursion? (I don't think it has ANYTHING to do with recursion)

Comment: @DuncanC, it was bad choice of word in the context, sorry for any confusion @Rob thanks for the Edit. Actually, It has nothing to do with recursion. I only  meant that i need to continuously format the `UILabel` text even already formatted text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following, namely strip out any thousands separators, get a number from that, and then reformat with the thousands separator:

```
@IBAction func didEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    guard let text = sender.text else { return }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

    // get thousands separator

    let thousandsSeparator = formatter.groupingSeparator ?? ","

    // strip thousands separators out

    let stripped = String(text.filter { return String($0) != thousandsSeparator })

    // now, re-insert them, if any

    if let number = formatter.numberFromString(stripped) {
        sender.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(number)
    }
}
```

---

Assuming you're hooking this up to "Editing Changed" so that it's constantly updated, this introduces a few issues. For example, to enter the trailing decimal place, you might have to manually check for that and allow that to be preserved:

```
@IBAction func didEditingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    guard let text = sender.text else { return }

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

    // get thousands separator

    let thousandsSeparator = formatter.groupingSeparator ?? ","

    // strip thousands separators out

    let stripped = String(text.filter { return String($0) != thousandsSeparator })

    // see if decimal place found, and if so, set fractional digits accordingly

    let decimalSeparator = formatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
    var fractionalDigits: Int?
    if let decimalSeparatorIndex = text.range(of: decimalSeparator)?.lowerBound {
        fractionalDigits = text[decimalSeparatorIndex...].count(of: "0123456789")
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = fractionalDigits!
    }

    guard
        let number = formatter.number(from: stripped),
        var result = formatter.string(from: number)
    else {
        // do whatever is appropriate if string isn't a number at all
        return
    }

    // re-add trailing decimal place only if decimal separator was found, but no fractional digits were

    if fractionalDigits == 0 {
        result += decimalSeparator
    }

    // update text field

    sender.text = result
}
```

Note, that uses this little extension:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func count(of string: String) -> Int {
        return reduce(0) { $0 + (string.contains($1) ? 1 : 0) }
    }
}
```

There are many other refinements you could tackle. For example, if the user is not at the end of the text field when they edit, this will reset the `selectedTextRange`. You also should probably implement `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to make sure that you cannot enter value at all where `stripped` would fail. Etc.

But hopefully this illustrates one approach for capturing text input and updating the result with the formatted decimal number.

---

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38003630/2).

Comment: Thanks! This is the Perfect solution. I also started off same way by taking out the separator before feeding string to numberFromString function but then later started facing issues with preserving decimal separator. This is the best solution for the given use case and by far i think the only way to achieve this. It did the job perfectly. Thanks again Rob.

Comment: will test it properly once.

Comment: Works like charm but there is need to add logic to preserve zeros too in the string after decimal separator  e.g. 1.0 , 1.00, 1.10, 1.010

Comment: Tweaked logic to handle trailing fractional zeros. Also updated for contemporary Swift versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the number formatter matches the strings that you pass to it. If there is any mismatch, it is going to return nil, and the doubleValue call is going to return 0.

If you have strings formatted for the US, with a grouping separator of a comma, then you should set the `groupingSeparator` property of the number formatter to a comma. Then the formatter should handle input strings like "1,234". As you say, "1,2345" is not a normal US format for displaying a number.

You might need to change the groupingSize setting as well (The string "1,2345" would have a groupingSize of 4, if I'm not mistaken.

Where are the strings you are parsing coming from? Do you know what locale they use? Is the user entering "1,2345" on a device that is set up using the `en-US` locale"? If so, why? That's not normal formatting for US English.

Comment: The digits getting appended on a button touchdown event  and shown on `UILabel` like a calculator. The locale is set to "en-US".  So, once `UILabel` displaying "1,234" and as soon as i hit button with title "5", the input string to formatter becomes "1,2345" and i expect formatter to return string as "12,345" as per US locale to be displayed as `UILabel` text.

Comment: Do you suggest i should use `groupingSeparator` and `groupingSize` properties explicitly? I assumed that formatter is already taking care of it , once i set the locale in my code.